# spike/peak removal/interpolation

Tags: algorithms, signal-processing

I have some signals that look like following:

[image]

I would like to remove the two peaks by doing linear interpolation, so I can get something like this:

[image]
where the orange line segment should replace the two peaks after the interpolation.

I understand this very difficult because even for human being you can do it differently like this:
[image]

or even this:
[image]

So it is really a challenging problem, and might not be a definite answer, but I just think something that looks comfortable, natural, and capturing details as much as possible.

I tried using mask, but edge is pretty noisy, and often times the width of the mask is far from the actual width of the spike. I also tried smoothing, and then applying finite difference to detect the starting and end position of the edges, but again it really does not as accurate as it should be.

I am wondering anyone has experience dealing with this problem? What algorithm I should use? Any literature describing the processing?

For this particular example, the data is here:

```
-0.0568
   -0.0536
   -0.0528
   -0.0500
   -0.0379
   -0.0169
   -0.0005
    0.0127
    0.0075
    0.0133
    0.0123
    0.0130
    0.0084
    0.0126
    0.0144
    0.0030
    0.0093
    0.0168
    0.0101
    0.0096
    0.0078
    0.0117
    0.0106
    0.0138
    0.0128
    0.0059
    0.0075
    0.0062
    0.0056
    0.0017
    0.0037
    0.0173
    0.0114
    0.0143
    0.0113
    0.0117
    0.0040
    0.0118
    0.0085
    0.0079
    0.0063
    0.0152
    0.0064
    0.0024
    0.0058
    0.0041
    0.0101
    0.0086
    0.0086
    0.0154
    0.0018
    0.0130
    0.0094
    0.0094
    0.0096
    0.0103
    0.0170
    0.0081
    0.0035
    0.0138
    0.0123
    0.0031
    0.0120
    0.0039
    0.0043
    0.0063
    0.0191
    0.0023
    0.0165
    0.0174
    0.0129
    0.0135
    0.0153
    0.0100
    0.0066
    0.0135
    0.0109
    0.0038
    0.0129
    0.0084
    0.0095
    0.0109
    0.0121
    0.0077
    0.0116
    0.0128
    0.0101
    0.0158
    0.0134
    0.0042
    0.0054
    0.0063
    0.0059
    0.0136
    0.0029
    0.0139
    0.0104
    0.0215
    0.0180
    0.0153
    0.0187
    0.0138
    0.0236
    0.0190
    0.0267
    0.0209
    0.0112
    0.0108
    0.0238
    0.0280
    0.0266
    0.0300
    0.0256
    0.0278
    0.0260
    0.0263
    0.0257
    0.0334
    0.0309
    0.0301
    0.0325
    0.0280
    0.0300
    0.0286
    0.0359
    0.0317
    0.0381
    0.0348
    0.0422
    0.0389
    0.0491
    0.1754
    0.4760
    0.8146
    1.0172
    1.0757
    0.9471
    0.8509
    0.7955
    0.7526
    0.7314
    0.7092
    0.7073
    0.6906
    0.6787
    0.6654
    0.6646
    0.6553
    0.6420
    0.6385
    0.6390
    0.6373
    0.6305
    0.6216
    0.6218
    0.6212
    0.6108
    0.6161
    0.6054
    0.6106
    0.6006
    0.6032
    0.6100
    0.6006
    0.5975
    0.6042
    0.6027
    0.6044
    0.6138
    0.6106
    0.6051
    0.6084
    0.6065
    0.6212
    0.6207
    0.6306
    0.6270
    0.6484
    0.6605
    0.6742
    0.6828
    0.6972
    0.7076
    0.7062
    0.6918
    0.6905
    0.6759
    0.6459
    0.6134
    0.5989
    0.5790
    0.5663
    0.5595
    0.5609
    0.5467
    0.5442
    0.5400
    0.5317
    0.5267
    0.5182
    0.5187
    0.5101
    0.4975
    0.4951
    0.4907
    0.4855
    0.4745
    0.4505
    0.4604
    0.5814
    0.7370
    0.8355
    0.9012
    0.9498
    0.9783
    1.0188
    1.0496
    1.0727
    1.1201
    1.1639
    1.2085
    1.2465
    1.2691
    1.3170
    1.3553
    1.4211
    1.4715
    1.5169
    1.5694
    1.5963
    1.6341
    1.6722
    1.7125
    1.7388
    1.7725
    1.8040
    1.8505
    1.8817
    1.9064
    1.9337
    1.9837
    1.9992
    2.0385
    2.0719
    2.1062
    2.1415
    2.1767
    2.2151
    2.2385
    2.2427
    2.2591
    2.2856
    2.3185
    2.3572
    2.3638
    2.3905
    2.4077
    2.4429
    2.4662
    2.4841
    2.4977
    2.5204
    2.5549
    2.5709
    2.5810
    2.6063
    2.6301
    2.6245
    2.6519
    2.6594
    2.6707
    2.6836
    2.7045
    2.7642
    2.8208
    2.8278
    2.8821
    2.8950
    2.9526
    3.0908
    3.1539
    3.1935
    3.1544
    3.1317
    3.1717
    3.1677
    3.1526
    3.1489
    3.1292
    3.1129
    3.1293
    3.1561
    3.1556
    3.1857
    3.1856
    3.1327
    3.1160
    3.0868
    3.1122
    3.1407
    3.1970
    3.2136
    3.2211
    3.2376
    3.2222
    3.2521
    3.3035
    3.4006
    3.5001
    3.5602
    3.5756
    3.6020
    3.6014
    3.5830
    3.5640
    3.5016
    3.4363
    3.3618
    3.3640
    3.4059
    3.4812
    3.4943
    3.5307
    3.5735
    3.5193
    3.5079
    3.5052
    3.4986
    3.4955
    3.4303
    3.3649
    3.3260
    3.2755
    3.1902
    3.0984
    3.0574
    3.0174
    2.9852
    2.9648
    2.9462
    2.9398
    2.9393
    2.9490
    2.9268
    2.9042
    2.9143
    2.9065
    2.9340
    3.0154
    3.0141
    3.0202
    3.0782
    3.1301
    3.1803
    3.2108
    3.2176
    3.2588
    3.2822
    3.3173
    3.3732
    3.3976
    3.4492
    3.4675
    3.5090
    3.5702
    3.5230
    3.4513
    3.3371
    3.2674
    3.2867
    3.3829
    3.4563
    3.5314
    3.5805
    3.6043
    3.6157
    3.6267
    3.6450
    3.6317
    3.5860
    3.4163
    3.3502
    3.3793
    3.3572
    3.5124
    3.8337
    4.2717
    4.6394
    4.8060
    4.7245
    4.5504
    4.3687
    4.3737
    4.6887
    5.4021
    6.0749
    6.5674
    6.7279
    6.8391
    6.8456
    6.8219
    6.8410
    6.7609
    6.5246
    5.7718
    4.4415
    3.5784
    3.4720
    3.3728
    3.4125
    3.5051
    3.4689
    3.2906
    3.2217
    3.1706
    3.1218
    3.3428
    3.7802
    4.5759
    5.3222
    5.6758
    6.0151
    6.1276
    6.1647
    6.0552
    5.9937
    5.9784
    5.7171
    5.0609
    4.8232
    4.2979
    3.7390
    3.3099
    2.9529
    2.6971
    2.6021
    2.5640
    2.6019
    2.6515
    2.6531
    2.6558
    2.7166
    2.7408
    2.8190
    2.8535
    2.8639
    2.8700
    2.7703
    2.6353
    2.5842
    2.5137
    2.4497
    2.3751
    2.3382
    2.1323
    1.8490
    1.6700
    1.5507
    1.4733
    1.4242
    1.3643
    1.2997
    1.2203
    1.1462
    1.0776
    0.9962
    0.8265
    0.4876
    0.1304
    0.0341
    0.0296
    0.0263
    0.0261
    0.0247
    0.0232
    0.0256
    0.0214
    0.0232
    0.0208
    0.0205
    0.0182
    0.0186
    0.0169
    0.0236
    0.0198
    0.0157
    0.0143
    0.0179
    0.0118
    0.0136
    0.0139
    0.0115
    0.0093
    0.0096
    0.0107
    0.0132
    0.0090
    0.0074
    0.0103
    0.0071
    0.0086
    0.0069
    0.0052
    0.0069
    0.0062
    0.0115
    0.0068
    0.0179
    0.0121
    0.0092
    0.0098
    0.0138
    0.0081
    0.0055
    0.0077
    0.0048
    0.0059
    0.0052
    0.0095
    0.0087
    0.0114
    0.0036
    0.0080
    0.0110
    0.0049
    0.0079
    0.0065
    0.0080
    0.0110
    0.0059
    0.0158
    0.0146
    0.0095
    0.0045
    0.0081
    0.0116
    0.0091
    0.0080
    0.0095
    0.0105
    0.0077
    0.0098
    0.0138
    0.0069
    0.0118
    0.0087
    0.0046
    0.0056
    0.0072
    0.0136
    0.0110
    0.0054
    0.0090
    0.0147
    0.0102
    0.0066
    0.0102
    0.0092
    0.0045
    0.0089
    0.0134
    0.0222
    0.0336
    0.0362
    0.0464
    0.0354
    0.0420
    0.0445
    0.0400
    0.0338
    0.0369
    0.0441
    0.0397
    0.0383
    0.0353
    0.0319
    0.0342
    0.0366
    0.0414
    0.0401
    0.0452
    0.0507
    0.0444
    0.0358
    0.0432
    0.0394
    0.0406
    0.0441
    0.0386
    0.0410
    0.0409
    0.0330
    0.0282
    0.0186
    0.0137
    0.0103
    0.0033
    0.0101
    0.0080
    0.0141
    0.0097
    0.0102
    0.0092
    0.0094
    0.0055
    0.0119
    0.0140
    0.0116
    0.0077
    0.0148
    0.0063
    0.0021
    0.0048
    0.0033
    0.0123
    0.0109
    0.0108
    0.0168
    0.0112
    0.0046
    0.0085
    0.0068
    0.0091
    0.0096
    0.0061
    0.0063
    0.0082
    0.0084
    0.0094
    0.0070
    0.0087
    0.0042
    0.0077
    0.0060
    0.0123
    0.0127
    0.0107
    0.0019
    0.0082
    0.0051
    0.0068
    0.0064
    0.0061
    0.0057
    0.0094
    0.0162
    0.0141
    0.0165
    0.0065
    0.0121
    0.0047
    0.0120
    0.0076
    0.0050
    0.0080
    0.0139
    0.0023
    0.0139
    0.0123
    0.0087
    0.0151
    0.0060
    0.0103
    0.0039
    0.0042
    0.0043
   -0.0011
    0.0080
    0.0028
    0.0074
    0.0042
    0.0018
    0.0087
    0.0049
    0.0076
    0.0156
    0.0076
    0.0091
    0.0056
    0.0091
    0.0075
    0.0012
    0.0056
    0.0123
    0.0137
    0.0087
    0.0025
    0.0084
    0.0104
    0.0086
   -0.0008
    0.0072
    0.0110
    0.0096
    0.0081
    0.0126
    0.0020
    0.0098
    0.0070
    0.0041
    0.0027
    0.0075
    0.0040
    0.0069
    0.0098
    0.0180
    0.0143
    0.0182
    0.0120
    0.0003
   -0.0011
    0.0063
    0.0104
    0.0043
    0.0128
    0.0075
    0.0051
    0.0065
    0.0063
    0.0005
    0.0097
    0.0099
    0.0084
    0.0105
    0.0017
    0.0080
    0.0140
    0.0054
    0.0048
```

Comment: Could you define peak? I mean, the peak might be top value, exceeding expectation value or sudden change in derivative. What is your real goal? Do you have a batch of similar problems? Where data came from? What should be under peak? Lerp? Smooth curve? Similar data based on reconstruction? What Y scale mean? Without any additional info, do smoothing filter on copy of signal, threshold it to find ranges, extrapolate from both sides and then pick some curve (say Catmull-Rom spline) to make it look. If this won't work, please include constraints into your question.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2786776/14578, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/347049/2921, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/92073/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Why do you want to do this linear interpolation thing rathe than apply some standard signal processing algorithm?